# Sha256 with byte[32] using CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptojs

Using CryptoJS i got as a result a byte[8] when I need a 32 one, this code exactly:

```
CryptoJS.SHA256(word);
```

How to get the 32?

Answer (score 1):

This feels a bit convoluted, but I don't have a lot of experience with CryptoJS so perhaps there's a solution that requires less steps:

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

let hash   = CryptoJS.SHA256('hello world');
let buffer = Buffer.from(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex), 'hex');
let array  = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

If you need a proper JS array (one for which `Array.isArray` returns `true`), you can use this:

```
let array = Array.from( new Uint8Array(buffer) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in my case:

```
let utf16le = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse(word);
let utf16Sha256 = CryptoJS.SHA256(utf16le);
return utf16Sha256.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

thanks to someone's else question

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem according to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

```
CryptoJS.SHA256(word).toString()
```

Comment: it gives a string as a result not the array