# How to generate a SHA256 hash of 32 bytes using nodejs (crypto) in order to avoid bad key size error thrown from tweetnacl.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sha256, cryptojs, nacl-cryptography

I am using the [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module of node.js to generate a SHA256 hash like this:

```
const key = crypto.createHmac('sha256', data).digest('hex');
```

Now, [tweetnacl](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js) throws the error: `bad key size` when the key is passed in the `secretbox`:

```
nacl.secretbox(data, Rnonc, key);
```

The parameters are converted into Uint8Array since the `secretbox` requires arguments to be Uint8Array.

The error: `bad key size` is throw from [here](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/nacl.js#L925) in `tweetnacl` since the `crypto_secretbox_KEYBYTES` is defined as `32` [here](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/nacl.js#L862). The problem is the key returned from `crypto` is in not 32 bytes size.

I have searched SO and relevant sites, but couldn't find any feasible solution but according to [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1692976.0) - the SHA256 hash converted to hex produces:

> 32 separate hexadecimal numbers (or 32 bytes)

How can I generate a SHA256 key of 32 bytes in order to avoid this error using node.js? Is there something I am doing wrong in generating the SHA256 hash?

Comment: Can you please try this? 

`const key = crypto.createHmac('sha256', data).digest('base64');`

Also try to print the key inside the function and try to process it locally once.

Comment: I tried with `crypto.createHmac('sha256', data).digest('base64')`, still getting `bad key size`

Comment: There are multiple calls for `checkLengths`. Can you please point the line where you are getting this error?

Comment: I am getting it from [here](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/nacl.js#L954)

Comment: Can you try adding a `cosole.log(k); cosole.log(k.length);` inside the function and see what k is? You may get a clue ..

Comment: For `key` I get a `Uint8Array` array as output like this `[98, 87, 122, 87, 77, 111, 83, 43, 83, 107, 101, 54, 101, 117, 120, 75, 78....`, of length `44`. Any idea how can I convert it to 32 bytes of size?

Comment: This link may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796371/sha256-with-byte32-using-cryptojs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet solved the issue of generating a 32 bytes SHA256 hash avoiding the bad key size error thrown from tweetnacl.js:

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

let hash   = CryptoJS.SHA256('hello world');
let buffer = Buffer.from(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex), 'hex');
let array  = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

This always generates a `Uint8Array` of 32 bytes size. Notice here I had to use the `crypto-js` module although I preferred to use the native `crypto` module but I guess I would just use it for now as it is a working solution.

Thanks to @Arihant for pointing to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796371/sha256-with-byte32-using-cryptojs) (check the comment section)